# Dynamic Sub calling in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with many subs doing different stuff. I have a "master" sub that decides which sub is to be executed according to data read from worksheets. After the "master" has identified the correct sub to run, I want it to call that sub so the procedure is executed.

In other words, I want something like this:

```
Sub Master()
Dim SubName as string
'Some code that determines SubName
Call SubName
End sub
```